# Turn on LED when manual switch ON only

Tags: led, solenoid

The circuit consists of a 12V DC supply, there is a GPIO to turn on the solenoid rated at 12V 500mA. Also, a manual switch is there to turn on the solenoid when needed.

The placement of LED and 1K resistor is such that LED would turn ON whenever Solenoid is turned on, be it either due to GPIO high OR by manual switch. My requirement is to Turn on a LED if Manual Switch is ON irrespective of GPIO level.

- Manual ON , GPIO ON : LED ON
- Manual ON, GPIO OFF : LED ON
- Manual OFF, GPIO ON : LED OFF
- Manual OFF, GPIO OFF : LED OFF

How can it be accomplished?

NOTE: TIP122 is transistor used. The diode is flyback diode

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: I remember you    ;)       Hey, why do you want to do this???    It doesn't make sense.  What you are asking for is "SWITCH ON, LED ON" and "SWITCH OFF, LED OFF".  Those are really the only 2 combinations you have specified.  The state of the transistor/solenoid would be irrelevant.  Are you sure this is what you want???

Comment: @KyleB Hi. Thanks. The reason i want a separate LED for Manual ON button is for end user to know he has turned ON solenoid using manual button. The MCU controls when to turn on or off the solenoid. Manual Switch is for override. So there needs to be an indication that the Switch has been turned ON.

Comment: Ahh... OK, so the switch still controls the solenoid... I didn't catch that.   Got it... Gimme another minute I'll sketch you something....     Important question though --- How much current can your CPU I/O pin provide???

Comment: Hi Kyle. Thank you so much! The gpio provides max 25mA.

Comment: Both the gpio or switch can turn on the solenoid. Do let me know if you need any other inputs @kyleB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a diode like in the following picture will do the job:

[image]

Comment: will it be able to handle spark as Kyle's answer indicates? What diode would you recommend?

Comment: sparks will be short circuited by the freewheeling (flyback) diode. don't forget that the flyback works when the swicth is open (high resistance).

Comment: Okay. Will 1n4001 suffice @paul?

Comment: yes 1N4001 or any 1N400x if you do not have 1N4001 will be perfect.

Comment: I already have 1N4007. Would that work?

Comment: Yes 1N4007 will work. (It will tolerate far more voltage than needed but there is no problem with that)

Comment: You won't get sparks as if there were no flyback, but you'll still get arcing on the switch contacts.   That diode won't start conducting instantly.

Comment: There will be no spark on the switch. Let us review why sparks are created: relay coil (inductance) cannot tolerate sudden change of current which usually tends to higher the voltage until it will breakdown in air. But meanwhile the fly-back diode will start conducting at a voltage too lower to the one that can produce an arc in the air.

Comment: @PaulGhobril   I do think the sparking is "probably" minor enough that it's not a big concern (although the 500mA vs 20mA does mean a "better" switch is required).  There will ALWAYS  be a spark when a mechanical switch is activated, even in a non-inductive load.  There HAS to be.  The metal contacts can't instantaneously move from 'open' to 'closed'... There will be a point where the breakdown of air (3kV/mm) is exceeded while the switch is moving.  Especially if he uses a 'slow' diode like the 1N4007 for the flyback.  Will it matter?  Probably not.  Depends on the switch and it's usage.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f72K7m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There's a million ways to do most anything.  What Paul drew is clever and would work.  So would this one.

Mine has 1 more component, but Pauls has two minor tricks you should be aware of...

One is that diode has to be able to handle all the solenoid current (500mA)... not all diodes can do this.    What I wrote uses 2 small-signal diodes --- 1N4148's can't handle 500mA (not even close).  So these 2 diodes would be cheaper, but there's 2 of them.  Pauls circuit, you'll need a power diode like 1N4001.

Another catch with his circuit, all the current flows through the switch so it also has to handle 500mA (and the associated spark that occurs when a coil is interrupted), with mine the current in the switch is a trickle and not inductive  i.e. you can use a smaller switch, or if using the same switch, it would likely last *MUCH* longer.

BTW, The 270 resistor is presuming a 5V I/O.   If it's only 3.3V, that resistor should be made smaller.

Comment: Just for simplicity I chose Paul, but if I could I'd also choose this as the accepted answer. Thanks Kyle for all the details!

Comment: Haha   don't worry, I don't take it personally   ;)

Comment: do you agree with Paul that flyback diode will take care of the sparks? Can 1N4007 suffice for flyback in his circuit?